# How to configure teamviewer so it does not load unless needed

Tags: teamviewer

I installed Teamviewer to help a friend (Afterwards I forcibly moved him to using Google Hangout) and noticed that it loads automatically a process even if I am not running teamviewer:

[image]

It does not show in the Startup Applications so I am guessing it is either hidden in the Startup applications or it is loaded by an option in a configuration file. I want to remove this automatic way of loading into memory so that it only works when I actually use teamviewer and not every time I boot the computer.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

If you mean teamviewer 8 try `sudo teamviewer --daemon disable` (disable teamviewer 8 autostart)

Comment: Nice one. That puppy will not be auto starting any time soon.

Comment: Yeah annoying, since tv8, tv7 was not auto-starting.

Comment: I got an error that I don't own some files, so I did it without sudo again, but it worked anyway

Answer (score 3):

I've had this problem just now, and solved it by changing the option "[int32] Always_Online" to "0" in the file /etc/teamviewer/global.conf. Basically, what you should is to access this file with sudo privileges, and change this line:

[int32] Always_Online = 1

For this one:

[int32] Always_Online = 0

Best regards! :)

Comment: Can't find this line. I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 (latest updates), TV version 11.0.67687

Answer (score 0):

Well, I can't find any autostart .desktop on the deb file, so it should either create it after someone launches the application or is auto-started by Wine(?).

Check both `/etc/xdg/autostart/` and `~/.config/autostart/` for a .desktop file which could be launching either Teamviewer of Wine. If you find any you can remove it or change any of those values:

```
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=false # disables autostart
Hidden=false                    # shows item on Startup Applications
```

Comment: it is not started from a .desktop file, but via /etc/init/teamviewerd.conf which can be configured like the other answer says.

Answer (score 0):

May be this resource could help you.

https://community.teamviewer.com/t5/TeamViewer-General/How-to-disable-teamviewerd-on-Debian/td-p/2088